# System.Data.OracleClient cannot be created in Web API service

Tags: c#, oracle, rest, iis, service

I have a Web API REST service written in C#. When tested from inside the IDE the service works as expected. Once the service is deployed to IIS every attempt to create an OracleConnection instance results in a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. The Oracle client has been installed on the server, all of the dll's are on theserver. All of the configurations is perfect. There are other SOAP services running on the same server connecting to Oracle using the same mechanisms and they all work. Please can someone give me some advice, or guidance.

Thanks in advance

Example of connection pattern being used (connection string is valid):

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        using (var command = new OracleCommand("storedproc", connection))
        {
            ...  
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (OracleException oe)
{
    ...  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...  
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the `connection` object is null?

Comment: Yes, i have thrown exceptions on the preceding and subsequent lines. The one on the preceding line is raised but the one after never sees the light of day.

Comment: Which lines are you talking about?

Comment: using (var connection = new OracleConnection())

Comment: That is the line which is failling

Comment: So calling `new OracleConnection()` throws a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception?

Comment: This may not address the issue directly, but have you tried switching to the Managed ODP.net?